# CSRF + кража кук

Tags: php, cookie, сессия, token

у себя на сайте я использую следующий механизм авторизации: запускаю сессию, изменяю значение в `SessionID(PHPSESSID)` на `случайный токен:csrf(ip+user_agent+login+etc)`

при любых "важных" действиях я проверяю вторую часть токена... Так же я не защищаю формы добавляя к ним скрытые поля, а делаю на сервере просто - `if(ip+user_agent+login+etc == $_COOKIE["SessionID"]) {}`... если украсть куки, и подставить на вредном сайте, то можно заставить пользователя выполнить какие-то действия.. подскажите, как это более правильно реализовать?

Comment: А какой толк от украденных кук будет, если они у вас завязаны на ip? Если только ip совпадают.

Comment: И вообще, раз у вас сессия, то ip и user_agent надо в сессию писать, а не в куку шифровать.

Comment: @maschine: Как правильно заметил Visman, в куках можно хранить не критичные данные - счётчики, выбранный язык/локализацию сайта. Сессионую куку обязательно создавать с флагом `HttpOnly`. CSRF-токен лучше создавать [правильным рендомом](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-security/blob/master/src/Security.php#L416) и записывать в сессию. Далее, добавлять в hidden поле формы или в параметр URL-а и сверять при каждом запросе.